# Unix file mode not working on Mac OS X - install4j

Tags: install4j

If I set the default Unix file mode in the "File Options" tab, these should work for all files an directories that I've defined in my distribution three but that didn't.
If I change the Unix file mode directly on the files/directories in my distribution three it works perfectly.

It seems that the global definitions aren't working correctly. Could that be a bug or I'm understanding things wrong?
Im using install4j 6.0.1

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default file mode is used if the "Unix file mode" check box is not selected for an entry in the distribution tree.

You can check the file .install4j/i4jparams.conf after the installation, locate the "fileOptions" element and check the "mode" attributes to see which modes the compiler actually used.

Comment: Hi Ingo... I understood... but it isn't working as you explained... if I set the default value for directory mode to 777 and check the i4jparams.conf file I see that the modes are still setted to 755. For files it works as expected. In other words: The default value for directories is not working!

Comment: I just fixed a bug in that area, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's no so urgent. The workaround (defining unix mode directly in the distribution tree) works fine. I gonna wait for the next release. Thanks for your help. PS. Do you speek german?